# Android SQLite. insert. android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException

Tags: android, sqlite

create db code

```
    StringBuilder my_db = new StringBuilder();
    my_db.append("create table " + "my_db" + " (");
    my_db.append("id integer unique," +
                                  "tmp_id integer unique," +
                                  "tmp_at datetime ," +
                                  "tmp_count integer," +
                                  "tmp_reason_code integer);");
    db.execSQL(unlocked_achievements.toString());
```

insert code

```
final String sql = "insert into my_db (id, tmp_reason_code, tmp_count, tmp_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
SQLiteDatabase db = LocalDB.getInstance().getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    stmt.bindLong(1, id);
    stmt.bindLong(2, 0);
    stmt.bindLong(3, 0);
    stmt.bindLong(4, tmp_id);
    stmt.execute();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

If the insert code starts, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException is generated.

Comment: I would suggest you to pull the table from your project and check them from SQLite Browser. It helps a lot at time in understanding what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have these in the table definition:

```
id     integer unique
tmp_id integer unique
```

So you already have `id` or `tmp_id` in your table and trying to insert them again is violating the unique constraints on those columns.